# separating columns from command into a new command

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I'm trying to create a script for automatic device creation.
I'm pretty far already, but I am stuck at one point.

The source file looks like this:

```
dev1 size 1024
dev2 size 1024
dev3 size 1024
dev4 size 512
dev5 size 512
```

In the script the source file is the variable $INVFILE. Then I issue the command

```
cat $INVFILE | awk '{print $3}' | sort | uniq -c
```

Which gives the following output:

```
   3 1024
   2 512
```

I want to use this output in the following command, so that it uses the different sizes, and their counts (for this example I'm using the first line only, but in the script I want to use both lines in a sort of "for i in" function).

```
create dev count=3 size=1024MB
```

How can I do this in the script? And is there an easier way instead of the "for i in" function?

Comment: Note that `awk` can take a file as an argument, there is no need for `cat` there. You could just do `awk '{print $3}' $INVFILE`. This is what is known as a [UUoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '{print $3}' $INVFILE | sort | uniq -c | \
while read a b ; do \
    create dev count=$a size=${b}MB ; \
done
```

**for** only uses one list item per loop cycle, **while read x_1 x_2 x_3...** uses however many **x_n***s* there are, (but never more items than happen to be in one line of the input file).

Note, *if* any of the input had more than two columns, change 'read a b' above to 'read a b c' -- the **$c** wouldn't be used in the loop, but it prevents read from assigning the rest of the line to **$b**.

---

The first line of pipes can be swapped out with **[datamash](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/)**, with *$a* & *$b* swapped in the loop:

```
datamash -W -s -g3 count 3 < $INVFILE | \
while read a b ; do \
    create dev count=$b size=${a}MB ; \
done
```

Comment: Just to be sure. The while read function will run the command for every line in of the output? I will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Yes _while read_ runs for every input line.

Comment: This was excatly what I needed! Thanks all!

Answer (score 4):

awk can do all the job.

try

```
awk '{ d[$3]++ ; } 
     END { for ( c in d ) 
        printf "create dev count=%d size=%dMB\n",d[c],c ;}' $INVFILE
```

and if it work :

```
awk '{ d[$3]++ ; } 
   END { for ( c in d ) 
         printf "create dev count=%d size=%dMB\n",d[c],c ;}' $INVFILE |
bash
```

Comment: +, but very complicated for a beginner...

Comment: I agree. A very personnal point of view is to avoid useless pipe and multiple command. however the best command is the one you understand. (specially if you are the one responsible for it).

Comment: @agc OK to break one line, but keep awk line in `pattern { action}` at least.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the 'uniq' - command has an option for ignoring n columns: '-f N'.

Afterwards you may put fields from an input into variables with 'read'.

So in total, the following command will pick the needed information from all lines of the input file:

```
cat input.txt | uniq -f2 -c | while read a b c d; do echo "command $a $d" ;done
```

Substitute "echo ..." with 
your command.

Comment: 1) Needs `sort` before `uniq` as per OP spec, (sorted by field yet).   2) Useless `cat`.

Comment: @agc - isn't your answer using an equally useless `cat` ?

Comment: @don_crissti, :  Yes, and with intent.  It's the OP's useless `cat`, the goal being to ease the `for` vs `while` learning curve.  OTOH gerhard d. is going for the full Monty with the most minimal command, so he _should_ "put out the cat".  I can revise my answer, (or add a minimalist addendum), but since it's gerhard's idea, he ought to have a few days dibs.

Comment: @agc - you can't be serious !

Comment: @don_crissti, lets focus on the code, not the coders.